# Merge two partition without gparted on Centos 6.*

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos, gparted

I have been trying to merge two partitions on my centos 6 virtual machine. I have only command line access to this machine. My system look like this:

```
[x@x-y ~]$lsblk
NAME                       MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sr0                         11:0    1 1024M  0 rom  
sda                          8:0    0  200G  0 disk 
├─sda1                       8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
├─sda2                       8:2    0 39.5G  0 part 
│ ├─vg_vts0-lv_root (dm-0) 253:0    0 35.6G  0 lvm  /
│ └─vg_vts0-lv_swap (dm-1) 253:1    0  3.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
└─sda3                       8:3    0  160G  0 part
```

I don't want to lose data from sda2, however I am fine with clearing data of sda3.
I tried fsdisk, but I am not sure how should I merge sda2 and sda3. Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: Which partitions do you want to merge?

Comment: Update: sda2 and sda3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are using LVM (Logical Volume Manager), which means that you can leave the existing partitions in place, and merge them at the "LVM" level, ie between the sdx block device and the Filesystem.  LVM is designed specifically to allow this kind of operation.

Any file system operation has some risk - so back up your data and check you are happy with the risks of the solution before attempting it, but

1. Using FDISK or similar modify the partition type for sda3 to "8e" 
    = Linux LVM.
2. Reload the partition information if possible, otherwise restart
    the VM to reread it - You may be able to do a "partprobe /dev/sda3"
3. Add the Physical volume - something like "pvcreate /dev/sda3"
4. Add /dev/sda3 to the volume group with "vgextend vg_vts0 /dev/sda3"
5. Expand your data partion with a command like lvextend -L +155G /dev/vg_vts0/lv_root   - Note this will increase the size of the partition by
   155 gigs, not 160 gigs.  This will leave you 5 gigs for playing arround with later on and may come in useful - especially if you want to start doing full disk backups using snapshots.
6. Expand the partition - if you are using EXT4, which you probably are, 
   resize4fs /dev/vg_vts0/lv_root    (It might be called resize2fs depending
   on your distro)

As an alternative (which better answers the question you ask, but is way, way more risky and does not buy you much) would be to repartition the underlying disks.  Using something like FDISK, delete partition 2 and partition 3, then create a new partition 2 using all the space - remembering to set the type to 8E.   Follow step 6 onwards above.   Again, this is a bad idea - LVM makes doing this even more risky then it would otherwise be - and it is risky - and defeats the purpose of LVM